# Is it possible to use docker with jrebel or dcevm

Tags: java, docker, jrebel, dcevm

I have been using docker for a few weeks on my development environment, and it is quite nice, I do not have to worry about config neither I need to run a full virtual machine to just run an application server (JBoss in my case).

However I seem to have gone back to the old days with compile, deploy, wait, test.

Now question is, is there any way to use tools such as jrebel or dcevm in order to speed this up? Further more, does this question make sense at all?

Comment: Is the issue that you are building a new container for every compile?  You could mount your compiled files into a more static container for quick iterations, then build a self-contained container when you are ready to ship.  See the [-v option](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)

Comment: @Bryan I am already using the -v option, but that does not solve the question, is it possible to run this either via JRebel or dcevm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why it isn't possible. Infact there is a [docker-jboss-jrebel](https://github.com/n3ziniuka5/docker-jboss-jrebel) container publicly available already. I have not tested it myself so I can't say for sure if there are issues.Have your tried running JRebel? did you see any problems?

Comment: The question is more related on how to determine which jvm will be running the application server. If I can customise that, then using dcevm would be simple and will allow me to write and test my code without deploying. Any idea on how to do so?

Comment: By which JVM do you mean which jvm version or which jvm instance? either way you would control that using your entry point definition.

Comment: I mean how can I tell docker, start jboss with THIS particular jvm (normally dcevm), so that I can do real how-swap.

Comment: How would you this outside docker? You would set the same command as your entry point or CMD in the docker container.